# Unable to boot Ubuntu after disconnecting power

Tags: dual-boot, boot-repair

I installed Ubuntu on laptop while it was in the Docking station. Entering BIOS with f9 every time I wanted to run Ubuntu. Both Windows and Ubuntu worked. When I booted up without the power cable connected to docking I got an error message. I tried to fix it with Boot-Repair, but it didn't work.
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/K67fdkcVzw/ and https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/YP5cDsR24V/

```
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi /efi/Boot/fbx64.efi 
                       /efi/Boot/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg /efi/HP/BiosUpdate/CryptRSA32.efi 
                       /efi/HP/BiosUpdate/CryptRSA.efi 
                       /efi/HP/BiosUpdate/HpBiosMgmt32.efi 
                       /efi/HP/BiosUpdate/HpBiosMgmt.efi 
                       /efi/HP/BiosUpdate/HpBiosUpdate32.efi 
                       /efi/HP/BiosUpdate/HpBiosUpdate.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 10 or 11
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda8: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

sdb: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the boot sector of 
                       sdb and looks at sector 0 of the same hard drive for 
                       core.img, but core.img can not be found at this 
                       location.
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/FD/sdb: /dev/sdb already mounted or mount point busy.


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS on sda8
OS#2:   Windows 10 or 11 on sda4

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: HD Graphics 5500 from Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, jammy, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: M71 Ver. 01.31(1.31) from Hewlett-Packard
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0000
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,GPT,9ce97918-1b6f-4bcd-9318-c314a211800f,0xfa000,0x32000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...1................
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(2,GPT,9ce97918-1b6f-4bcd-9318-c314a211800f,0xfa000,0x32000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)


============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda2    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda4    : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sda5    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sda6    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sda8    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ng, update-grub,    end-after-100GB

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda2    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda4    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda5    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda6    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda8    : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda2    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda4    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda5    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda6    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda8    : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk identifier: 89950D94-69E5-4DC0-AD48-1D6A080A32A0
         Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
sda1       2048    1023999   1021952   499M Windows recovery environment
sda2    1024000    1228799    204800   100M EFI System
sda3    1228800    1261567     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
sda4    1261568  417268988 416007421 198.4G Microsoft basic data
sda5  878751744  880148479   1396736   682M Windows recovery environment
sda6  880150528 1000212479 120061952  57.3G Microsoft basic data
sda8  417269760  568866815 151597056  72.3G Linux filesystem
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk sdb: 7.47 GiB, 8019509248 bytes, 15663104 sectors
Disk identifier: F45E2FA1-C5A6-4D79-876F-C8245AF921E0
       Start      End Sectors  Size Type
sdb1       64  9828451 9828388  4.7G Microsoft basic data
sdb2  9828452  9838519   10068  4.9M EFI System
sdb3  9838520  9839119     600  300K Microsoft basic data
sdb4  9842688 15663040 5820353  2.8G Linux filesystem

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:512GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA MTFDDAK512MAY-1A:;
1:1049kB:524MB:523MB:ntfs:Basic data partition:hidden, diag;
2:524MB:629MB:105MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
3:629MB:646MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
4:646MB:214GB:213GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
8:214GB:291GB:77.6GB:ext4::;
5:450GB:451GB:715MB:ntfs::hidden, diag;
6:451GB:512GB:61.5GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
sdb:8020MB:scsi:512:512:gpt:Kingston DataTraveler 2.0:;
1:32.8kB:5032MB:5032MB::ISO9660:hidden, msftdata;
2:5032MB:5037MB:5155kB::Appended2:boot, esp;
3:5037MB:5038MB:307kB::Gap1:hidden, msftdata;
4:5039MB:8019MB:2980MB:ext4::;

Free space >10MiB: ______________________________________________________________

sda: 277767MiB:429078MiB:151311MiB

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                    PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                                
├─sda1 ntfs     E2EAD0B7EAD088E5                     9e05fdb7-d3fc-425d-9752-7cfbea740eb1 Återställning            Basic data partition
├─sda2 vfat     94D1-EE02                            9ce97918-1b6f-4bcd-9318-c314a211800f                          EFI system partition
├─sda3                                               c5009914-32b4-4c3d-b238-c011e0c102ec                          Microsoft reserved partition
├─sda4 ntfs     8EFED92AFED90B7B                     bb91de3d-41b7-42e9-a74b-a08c03b30d9a                          Basic data partition
├─sda5 ntfs     CAF43909F438F971                     9c169db3-fb7f-4987-9d04-3a49a0d4cb97                          
├─sda6 ntfs     900804E20804C964                     4b49118c-952a-4758-b5df-e3b72408694f Ny volym                 Basic data partition
└─sda8 ext4     86e8b7e2-0c4a-4d3e-8303-92ca5ce2e94a 3c44f663-96c6-4440-84f2-20b9432b176e                          
sdb    iso9660  2023-08-08-01-19-05-00                                                    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS amd64 
├─sdb1 iso9660  2023-08-08-01-19-05-00               f45e2fa1-c5a6-4d79-876e-c8245af921e0 Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS amd64 ISO9660
├─sdb2 vfat     F7DB-4D56                            f45e2fa1-c5a6-4d79-876d-c8245af921e0 ESP                      Appended2
├─sdb3                                               f45e2fa1-c5a6-4d79-876c-c8245af921e0                          Gap1
└─sdb4 ext4     b01668d5-38aa-4b8f-b4e9-1dc35e60b568 cd540aed-edbe-5a41-b9b4-459f1c54b065 writable                 

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                                               Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1                                                       489M   2% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sda5                                                      72.8M  89% /mnt/boot-sav/sda5
/dev/sda6                                                     952.1M  98% /mnt/boot-sav/sda6
/dev/sda8                                                      53.1G  20% /mnt/boot-sav/sda8
/dev/sdb1                                                          0 100% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/sda1                                                     fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda5                                                     fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda6                                                     fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda8                                                     ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sdb1                                                     iso9660         ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048,iocharset=utf8

===================== sda2/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

search.fs_uuid 86e8b7e2-0c4a-4d3e-8303-92ca5ce2e94a root hd0,gpt8 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

====================== sda8/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu   86e8b7e2-0c4a-4d3e-8303-92ca5ce2e94a
Windows Boot Manager (on sda2)   osprober-efi-94D1-EE02
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sda8/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=86e8b7e2-0c4a-4d3e-8303-92ca5ce2e94a /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=94D1-EE02  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

======================= sda8/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

==================== sda8: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 261,176197052 = 280,435806208  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 244,219722748 = 262,228930560  boot/vmlinuz                                   2
 219,013923645 = 235,164409856  boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-26-generic                  1
 244,219722748 = 262,228930560  boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-21-generic                  2
 219,013923645 = 235,164409856  boot/vmlinuz.old                               1
 257,878887177 = 276,895346688  boot/initrd.img                                4
 257,994480133 = 277,019463680  boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-26-generic               5
 257,878887177 = 276,895346688  boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-21-generic               4
 257,994480133 = 277,019463680  boot/initrd.img.old                            5

===================== sda8: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18683 Dec 18  2022 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43031 Dec 18  2022 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14387 Dec 18  2022 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13369 Dec 18  2022 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1372 Dec 18  2022 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   700 May 17  2023 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Dec 18  2022 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Dec 18  2022 41_custom



Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will purge (in order to unsign) and reinstall the grub-efi of
sda8,
using the following options:  sda2/boot/efi
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file



Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS entry (sda2/efi/****/grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.
If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\****\grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message)
```

Comment: The ubuntu pastebin is behind a login wall.

Comment: I think you need ubuntu one account to see it, I do not know how to open it for everyone.

Comment: It seems to be to large to post it here

Answer (score 0):

Check the MBR of the hard drive. Maybe you need a bootable disk or usb for that.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1342797)